# What is an algorithm/structure that can be used to effectively find if a object matches any of a set of patterns?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, tree

A pattern is a hash with values and functions. For example:

```
pattern = {a:1,b:2,c:function(x){ return x<5; }}
```

There is a function that checks if an object matches a pattern. For example, an object will match the pattern above if obj.a == 1, obj.b == 2 and obj.c < 5. Some tests:

```
matches(pattern,{a:1,b:3,c:2}) == false // because b != 2
matches(pattern,{a:1,b:2,c:7}) == false // because c >= 5
matches(pattern,{a:1,b:2,c:3}) == true //fine
matches(pattern,{a:1,b:2,c:2,d:4}) == true //no problems in having extras
```

Suppose that I have a set of patterns and I want to find if an object matches any of those patterns. I could check one by one, but, this way, I have an O(n) complexity, where n is the number of patterns. I have a feeling that this can be optimized if I use the set of patterns to build some other structure; but I'm not sure what that structure could be. Thoughts?

Comment: How is this a haskell question?

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't resist calling the attention of some Haskell people. That's bad, I know, sorry. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: (Note: I have already asked a similar question but I still couldn't solve the problem.)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) (Or optimize it to [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) data structure). This requires reading each relevant variable only once during evaluation of each object.

A BDD is a way to evaluate a logical formula, in your case the logical formula is

```
pattern_1 OR pattern_2 OR pattern_3 OR .... OR pattern_n
```

Comment: to be honest that article on Wikipedia is kinda poor. I don't have a clear idea on how to implement a decision tree for this problem. I'm researching, will update on later. Thanks.

Comment: @Dokkat maybe [this intro](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.88.9410%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=iES_UJyHOIfKsga3mIDgCQ&usg=AFQjCNHPzH1BgC2EHdPdzeQWKtRVVYs2Ig&sig2=_2nEuexDMk8im2qD4LUJZQ&cad=rja) can be more helpful. Let me know if you have specific question regarding the BDD data structure or how to use it for your case (or, if you feel it is getting off-scope, ask a new question regarding the issue you have, and comment to me so I'll see the 2nd question).